# How to fix "mypy failed with error: Daemon has died . See Output panel for details." error in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mypy

I'm using the Mypy extension in VSCode, and it's giving me the error `mypy failed with error: Daemon has died . See Output panel for details.`

When I open the Output panel, it doesn't give me much more info than just telling my that it tried to run `dmymy.EXE` but that it had died.

**How do I get the Mypy extension working again?**

I've tried searching for this error on Google to no avail, and I've also tried rebooting VSCode, which gives me the same error every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open up a Command Prompt (on Windows) or Terminal (non-Windows). Copy/paste the location of the `dmypy.EXE` script that it tried to run (from the output panel). Put `start` after the script. This will start the daemon.

The command looked like this for me:

`C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\dmypy.EXE start`

Now, reboot VS Code (I'm not sure if this is even needed), and the mypy extension should work again.

Comment: This isn't really a solution. I would like to know why it's dying, and fix that, so I don't have to keep restarting it every time I see this.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't identify any root causes - this is because I was unable to determine what the root cause was, much less fix it. If you (or anyone else) is able to figure out the root cause, please leave a comment! If you (or anyone else) is able to figure how to solve the root cause, please leave an answer!

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Nope. If I did, I would have updated the answer.